# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenv'

Tags: python, macos, terminal

when I try to run virtualenv in command line in mac, it says

```
from virtualenv.__main__ import run_with_catch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenv'
```

but I am able to locate virtualenv with `which virtualenv`

```
/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
```

Comment: That's the path to an executable, not the path to a Python module.  It's easy to get tangled in MacOS because you have both Python 2 and Python 3.  Check the first line of that file to see if it is executing the one you want.

Comment: how do I know if it's executing the one I want? I only see that it's using /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3

Comment: The issue comes around if, for example, you are trying to run `python3`, but your `pip` is installing in Python 2.  That's why people suggest using `python -m pip install xxxx`, because then you get the same Python command.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `virtualenv` is not installed as a Python package. A simple `pip install virtualenv` should do the trick.

Comment: it didn't, I installed virtualenv